# Creating a tabbed browser in C#

Tags: c#, tabs, webbrowser-control

I am trying to create a 'tabbed' web browser in my C# program following the example I found at: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6e17c7/how-to-create-a-simple-multi-tabbed-webbrowser-in-C-Sharp/

However, having copied the code from this tutorial, and tried compiling it in Visual Studio, I get a compile error that says:

> Type 'Form1' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types

The code I am trying to run is:

```
namespace testBrowser
{
  public partial class Form1: Form
  {
    WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    TabControl tabControl1 = new TabControl();
    TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
        tabPage.Text = "New Page";
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tabPage);
        //WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Parent = tabPage;
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser.CanGoBack)
        {
            webBrowser.GoBack();
        }else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot go back");
        }
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = webBrowser.Url.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

I can't see `.ctor` anywhere in the code... what does this compile error mean? The line it's complaining about is `public Form1()`

Comment: `.ctor` means [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx). You probably already have a class named `Form1` which in its turn already has a constructor with no parameters.

Comment: It seems there was another class automatically generated when I created the project, which had that name...

Comment: However, now I have the code running- it's not doing what it says it does... It should show a window with a browser embedded, and the capability to open new tabs within that window. However, all I'm getting is a blank window, with no capabilities other than minimize, maximize and close... any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is partial , so you probably have the `Form1()` constructor defined in another source file for your partial class and `.ctor` It's just shorthand for "constructor" and it's what the constructor is called in IL.

Comment: Thanks- this was the case.